# Two Components, one is recognized, the other triggers the `[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component:` warning

Tags: vuejs3

I have two components I'm trying to use without `is="vue:<<component-name>>"` for reasons. For background:

• The project was generated using Vue CLI
• I'm having Vue parse a large part of the DOM on the fly
• Both components are in SFC `.vue` files, and both are defined in the entry script with Vue's `defineAsyncComponent()`

What I want, for convenience:

```
<div id="app">
  <Component></Component>
  <ComponentTwo></ComponentTwo>
</div>
```

I ran into an issue early on with the `<Component></Component>` syntax. Which is where I learned that the on-the-fly compilation may necessitate the (not-as-pretty) `<div is="vue:component"></div>` syntax.

If that was it, fine. It's not that pretty but whatever. There are tradeoffs everywhere.

But. As I built out other components, I noticed that I was able to get away with `<Component></Component>`. Yay! Awesome. So. I started building out the next one using the same pattern. And that's when I ran into that:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: componenttwo 
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
at <App>
```

I am mystified as to the difference. I went so far as to strip `ComponentTwo` down to the following, thinking maybe I was doing something naughty *within* the SFC:

```
<template>
    <div>ComponentTwo</div>
</template>
<script>
import { ref } from "vue";
export default {
    name: "ComponentTwo",
    setup( props ) {
        const Data = ref([]);
        return { Data }; 
    }
}
</script>
```

No love.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE** Out of desperation, I tried importing the known-working component **as** `<ComponentTwo>` and it *still* fails in precisely the same way.

**UPDATE to the UPDATE** Changing `<ComponentTwo>`'s name/reference to "Baz" — so `"Baz": defineAsyncComponent(() => import("./path/to/component-two.vue"))` in the main view-model's `components` registry, and `<Baz></Baz>` in the markup — "fixed" it. Could the… the PascalCase *name* be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the PascalCase *because* I am parsing the DOM. As **clearly** stipulated
in the Vue Docs [DOM Template Parsing Caveats](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dom-template-parsing-caveats).

Leaving this here in case anyone else is searching for help on this.